# ConvertFrom-Json not converting datetime

Tags: json, powershell, datetime

`ConvertFrom-Json` fails to convert datetime strings to datetime objects.
In the example below the type is `String` but I would have expected `DateTime`.

```
$data = '[{"start":"04/15/2016 15:47:41"},{"start":"04/15/2016 16:47:41"}]' |
        ConvertFrom-Json
$data[0].start.GetType().Name
```

Is there a workaround for this other than going through the array and explicitly cast the type?

Answer (score 3):

`ConvertFrom-Json` doesn't fail. Your `start` values are defined as strings (since [JSON](http://www.json.org/) doesn't have a "date" data type), so the cmdlet correctly treats them as such.

Convert the property in question to a `DateTime` value if you require that data type. In your case casting should suffice:

```
$data = '[{"start":"04/15/2016 15:47:41"},{"start":"04/15/2016 16:47:41"}]' |
        ConvertFrom-Json |
        Select-Object *,@{n='start';e={[DateTime]$_.start}} -Exclude start
```

but that works only if your date string is in a format PowerShell recognizes. If the format is not recognized you'll have to [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the string:

```
$fmt     = '...'   # format string
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.start, $fmt, $culture)
```

Comment: Recognized formats for casting are basically the US format (mm/dd/yyyy) and ISO-8601 (yyyy-mm-dd), either with or without a time.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell 7.0.3, it seems ConvertFrom-JSON **does** convert to DateTime *at least in some cases*.

But IMVHO it does it incorrectly:

```
$date = "2020-09-07T09:44:13.769Z"
$date
[datetime] $date

$data = ('[{"start":"' + $date + '"}]') |  ConvertFrom-Json
$data[0].start.GetType().Name
$data[0].start
```

outputs:

```
2020-09-07T09:44:13.769Z

Monday, September 7, 2020 11:44:13
DateTime
Monday, September 7, 2020 09:44:13
```

As a reference, Windows PowerShell 5.1 outputs:

```
2020-09-07T09:44:13.769Z

Monday, September 7, 2020 11:44:13
String
2020-09-07T09:44:13.769Z
```

Comment: FWIW, here's my current workaround:


    $JSONdata = (Invoke-WebRequest $url).Content
    $marker = '#@#@#'
    $JSONdata2 = $JSONdata -replace '("timestamp":")([^"]+)(")', ('$1' +         $marker + '$2' + $marker + '$3')
    $objects = ($JSONdata2 | ConvertFrom-Json).items | Foreach-Object {     $_.timestamp= [datetime] ($_.timestamp-replace $marker, ''); $_ }


HTH

Comment: maybe powershell expects a UTC datetime? what is your locale (Get-Culture)

Comment: full details about this issue can be found at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13592